# jQuery Accordion Menu - Keep Active Menu open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can not keep my Menu opened and I am having problem to follow to the Link of the Menu instead to to slide down. The slide down should be done by right floated counter.

The Code to keep opened at current page

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#cssmenu ul li.has-sub').parent().show();
    $('#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul').show();
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub ul').show();
});
```

My Example Code: http://jsfiddle.net/5abCc/

Thanks!

Comment: You want to toggle on clicking counter?

Comment: I think that you need to approach ajax or use cookies for keeping menu open..

Comment: @RohanKumar Yes I want toggle on click at counter, keep it opened if the link follow the url "Company" for ex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `open` class to your active ul like,

**HTML**

```
<li class='has-sub open'><a href='javascript:;'><span>Company</span></a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='javascript:;'><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='javascript:;'><span>Location</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#cssmenu li.has-sub.active ul').show();
});
```

To add click event on span try this,

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a .cnt').click(function() {
       // ----------------^ span counter element
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   
    var checkElement = $(this).parent('a').next();
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }       
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5abCc/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But the Class "open" keeps the Menu opened all the time. It should keep opened only if you are on the Page.
**edit**
I did not read to "active" ul.. You saved my day! Thanks